# how to add element right after another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html structure like below:

```
<div class="element1>

</div>
```

I want to create another div.element right after div.element1 so I use `element2.appendTo("div.element1")` but it's being created like below:

```
<div class="element1>
 <div class="element2">

 </div>
</div>
```

What I really what to be done is like below:

```
<div class="element1>

</div>
<div class="element2">

</div>
```

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `insertAfter()` :-

```
$(".element2").insertAfter($(".element1"));
```

Comment: I'll do it after 3 minutes.

Comment: downvoter ..give me one reason and if you are here to just downvote unnecessarily then you have no rights to be here .

Answer (score 2):

You should use *[after](http://jqapi.com/#p=after)* to insert elements as you want.

Try it:

```
$('.element1').after(element2);
```

Comment: I don't know why but your answer didn't work out very well. I check the element after creating it with Google Developer Tools but the element wasn't there.

Comment: It depends on your code, how do you add the element? In my example I add "element2", but I don't know what's the value of element2 in your code.

Comment: I tried the code on a blank page but neither that worked. Maybe I got the idea of the .after function wrong

Comment: It's very weird, this function works correctly. If you want you can share more code and I'll check it. I think it depends on the _element2_ variable.

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery you can user after or insert to the parent:

```
$('#element1').after('#element2')    
$('#element1').parent().append('#element2')
```

Comment: selectors are `classes` not `ids` . Read the question properly .